# Using Cursors and ListView Question

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-listview

I am stuck on this!  I have a listView populated by a a cursor.  My question is how can i get the specific item information from the cursor when a certain position in the listview is selected.  For example,  i select the third index in the listView, I want the information associated with that index from the cursor.  How can I do that?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `onListItemClicked()` method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    yourCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    yourRowId = yourCursor.getLong(0);
}
```

Your `Activity` must extend `ListActivity` for this to work as expected, like so:

```
public class YourActivity extends ListActivity {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating listview from cursor.So i am assuming that your list item 0 comes from Cursor's first record and so on.So if you click list item at position 3 you can move to cursor corresponding position by cursor.moveToPosition(3).Then can work accordingly